# Reading .bin or .dat file in Python

Tags: python, binaryfiles, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, lfsr

I am generating a binary file. I opened it using hexdump, it looks like this below 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Blgo.png)

But when I try to read this file in python using 
`file = open("lfsr.bin","rb")
data = file.read(10)
print data`

It's printing blank/empty 
But if I do

```
print repr(data)
```

It prints

```
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01'
```

How can I read this file in chunks of 1023? This file is actually an o/p of  PRN generator code.

Comment: `file.read(1023)`?

Comment: Why are you concerned on how it *prints*? It's binary data. It is not meant to "print". And as you already tested, it still gets *read* correctly, and that should be the only thing that counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can seem those first 10 bytes in the file (or all the bytes, it seems from the image) are either `0x00` or `0x01`. In [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/), those are all non-printable characters, so if you attempt to `print` them as a string you won't see anything - but the bytes are read. Printing it with `repr` works because `repr` gives you a "string representation of the object", so you can see the actual bytes in there.

As suggested, just do `data = file.read(1023)` to read a block of 1023 bytes from the file.

Note: This is made somewhat less confusing in Python 3, where data read from a binary file is returned as a `bytes` object and `str` is a distinct type with decoded string representation. In that case, printing `data` would show something like what you get from `repr` in Python, because `bytes` objects are not assumed to represent text and so it is preferred to show their contents even if it contains non-printable characters.

Comment: @YaaseenMohamed No problem. If you feel the answer solved your question, please consider marking it as accepted.